# Return output of Java Exec when providing array

Tags: java, exec

I'm using java's `exec()` to run some *nix system commands, specifically a python script, but the problem is more general.

```
import java.io.*;

public class JRC {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String s[] = {"/bin/bash", "-c",
                 "source venv/bin/activate;python mergeExcel.py '/home/201811/'"};
        try{
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(s);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("exception: ");
                    e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The above code works, in accordance with the extent to which mergeExcel.py works.
However, I can't figure out how to print to stdout from python.

Here's my attempt, which only works if we `exec()` a simple string such as `"ps -ef"`, rather than the array of strings i'm using.

```
try {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(s);

    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new
   InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

    BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new
         InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

    while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
    while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    System.exit(0);
}
```

This actually results in a compilation error of incompatible types, java.lang.String instead of the required java.lang.String[].

How can I can print output from the `source venv/..` command and the `python` command?

Comment: This appears to have very little to do with `Runtime.exec()`. Of course if `s` is a `String[]` then you cannot use it where a `String` is required, as these are different types.  Why don't you simply declare a new variable of the correct type to receive the results of your `readLine()`s?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the commenter, it's trivial to declare some temporary strings to print from stdout and stderr, though perhaps another user has a more elegant solution

```
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(s);

        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new
             InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new
             InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

        String stdi;
        while ((stdi = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(stdi);
        }

        String stderr;
        while ((stderr = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(stderr);
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
```